# How do I get the Bootstrap 4 sidenav menu to close on link click

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, sidebar

I have started to modify the getbootstrap template found **[HERE](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/offcanvas/)**

I can´t manage to get the menu to close on click on a link inside the menu when on mobile if it is a anchor link, I think it is because the page doesn´t reload so..

How can I get the behavior I look for.

Have tried all possible solutions given about a normal dropdown menu but that doesn´t work for sidenav..

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with a little jQuery...

```
  $('.navbar-nav>li>.nav-link').on('click', function(){
     $('.offcanvas-collapse').toggleClass('open')
  })
```

Demo: https://www.codeply.com/p/2py26A0JW0

Comment: Thanks, Tried something similar but targeted the wrong class.. Works like a charm! :)